# javascript regex to find specific html tag details

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, regex

i want a regex to find out **specific html tag** details.

i tried bellow 2 regex :

```
<\s*tag[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*/\s*tag>

<tag[^<>]*>.+?<\/tag>
```

bellow are the **2 test cases**  for 1st regex :

in **1st example** i am getting **correct** result but in the **example 2** i am getting **wrong** result.
where in both the cases in-puts are almost same.

1st case : all are as **individual string** and 
2nd case : as a **single string**.

```
===================================
Example 1 Input
===================================
<tagX>AAA</tagX>
<tag>GGG</tag>
<tag id="tag896">HHH</tag>
<tagY>III</tagY>
<tag id="tag017">JJJ</tag>
<tag>KKK</tag>
===================================
Output 1 // Correct
===================================
<tag>GGG</tag>
GGG
<tag id="tag896">HHH</tag>
HHH
<tag id="tag017">JJJ</tag>
JJJ
<tag>KKK</tag>
KKK


===================================
Example 2 Input (as a single string)
===================================
<tagX>AAA</tagX><tag>GGG</tag><tag id="tag896">HHH</tag><tagY>III</tagY><tag id="tag017">JJJ</tag><tag>KKK</tag>
===================================
Output 2 // Wrong
===================================
<tagX>AAA</tagX><tag>GGG</tag>
AAA</tagX><tag>GGG

<tag id="tag896">HHH</tag>
HHH

<tagY>III</tagY><tag id="tag017">JJJ</tag>
III</tagY><tag id="tag017">JJJ

<tag>KKK</tag>
KKK
```

here exactly i want the details of **(tag)** but in 2nd case its fetching ***(tag) + (tagX) + (tagY)*** details.

***my input is similar to 2nd input...***

its lil ***urgent***... can i get a solution for this.

thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem in the Regular Expressions you've written, is that you allow `<tagX>` (for example) to be the opening tag if there's `' that's supposedly closes it on the same line.

Your problem with using Regular Expressions in this case, is that you might get a bad result if the XML is:

```
<tag></tag>
<tagX></tagX>
<tag></tag>
```

If all the tags are inline, you could get the whole thing, so be very careful.

I'd work with something like (this works with the above example):

```regex
 <\s*tag((\s+[^<>]+\s*>)|(\s*>))[^<>]*<\s*\/tag\s*>
```

Here, I allow all the whitespaces which are valid, but I don't allow nested tags, so the above example will work. Moreover, If you allow nested tags, no REGEX will work. Look at this example:

```
<tag> <tagX> <tag> </tag> </tagX> </tag>
```

Though, in this example, you will get `<tag> <tagX> <tag> </tag>` as a valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the regex below and its working fine...

```
<tag( [^<>]+)?>(.+?)<\/tag>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET (and for some reason, you are sure about your XML and don't need to use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)), you may try this:

```
<tag(?:>|(?: .*?>))(.*?)</tag>
```